# Java Code within Lambda Call seems not to be executed (RabbitMQ Consumer, GZip Operation)

Tags: java, lambda, rabbitmq, base64, payload

The following Java code does not work as expected:

```
messageChannel.basicConsume("QueueName", false, (consumerTag, message) -> {
        String payloadString = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("payloadString=" + payloadString);
        
        try {
            String jsonString = GzipUtil.unzip(payloadString);
            System.out.println("jsonString=" + jsonString);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }, consumerTag -> {}
);
```

The try catch block does not work within this Lambda call. Everything else works (like the assignment and printing of payloadString). When I call the function GzipUtil.unzip(), it seems the code is not executed.

```
public static String unzip(String putBase64EncodedGzippedStringHere) throws Base64DecodingException {
        byte[] compressed = Base64.decode(putBase64EncodedGzippedStringHere);

        if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot unzip null or empty bytes");
        }
        if (!isZipped(compressed)) {
            System.out.println(compressed);
        }
        
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
            //System.out.println(output.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to unzip content", e);
    }
    return output.toString();
    }
```

When I run GzipUtil.unzip() in a seperate process like the following...

```
String byteString = "J3sIABC...IWJ==";
try {
    String s = GzipUtil.unzip(byteString);
    System.out.println(s);
        
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
}
```

... it works! What is wrong with placing the code within this Lamdba thing?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

When you put in a dummy string within the Lambda operation, it is working! So it must be something with the function call unzip().

```
try {
    String jsonString = "test";//GzipUtil.unzip(payloadString);
    System.out.println("jsonString=" + jsonString);
            
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Comment: I can't see the problem ... but you don't need to nest the *try with resources* 4 deep.  You can use just one of them with 4 resource variables.

Comment: Implemented. Thanks. Anyway, it's not running my function...